# In 64-bit MongoDB When the sharding process starts from one shards to another shards?

Tags: mongodb

I am undergoing a unit test in 64-bit mongodb in 64-bit linux machine.I have two shards both of the shards are configured in the local machine for testing purpose.So When the Sharding process starts over from the one shards to another?.Whether i have to give any size limit for the first shard so that once the size exceeded in first shard then it will go to the next shard?Please give me a solution.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in a given collection is stored in "chunks" of data in a contiguous/order preserving manner, by default 200MB in size. Once a chunk reaches this size, it will then split into 2. And then once a shard has an imbalance of data, mongo will then start to rebalance the data by moving chunks around between shards - so it's these "chunks" of data that are being moved.

So by default, you would need to populate a collection with a reasonable amount of data in order to end up with multiple chunks of 200MB which then start to be moved around between your shards. For testing purposes, you can change this chunk size (e.g. first time I played around with it, I set it to 1MB) by setting the --chunkSize argument on the mongos process. This means you only need a few MB of data in the collection before you start seeing sharding kick in.

Here's a great example setup for testing out sharding which explains the chunkSize:
 http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/A+Sample+Configuration+Session

Here's the introduction to sharding:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-Chunks